# How to find values from a list within a tuple within a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tuples

A database list contains tuples and each tuple contains a unique identifier string and a list of strings associated with it, like so:

```
example = [("id1",["value1","value2","value3"]),
           ("id2",["value4","value5"]),
           ("id3",["value3","value6"])]
```

As you can see, a string value can appear for multiple identifiers, as is the case with 'value3', which corresponds to both 'id1' and 'id3'.

I am interested in writing a function that takes the database and a string value as arguments and returns a list of all the IDs to which these strings correspond, like so:

```
lookScan :: database -> string -> [id]
```

So the result of `lookScan example "value3"` should be `["id1", "id3"]`

I have been scratching my head for days now and whenever I seem to be on the verge of cracking this, I always get a bunch of perplexing errors. I know it is supposed to be done with two guards that make it a recursive solution but the internal logic escapes me.

What I have so far:

```
lookScan ((id, stringsList):allEntries) string
| -- code if equality
| -- code if no equality
```

A particularly elusive problem of this is how to take each element of 'stringsList' and compare it with the argument 'string' so I can check for equality.

Any sort of help, even the tiniest hint, would be immensely appreciated! Thank you all in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with [**`elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) to check if an item is an element of a list (even from any `Foldable)`.

Your function thus looks like:

```
lookScan :: Eq v => [(k, [v])] -> v -> [k]
lookScan [] _ = []
lookScan ((id, ls): otherEntries) query
    | elem query ls = …
    | otherwise = …
```

where you need to fill in the `…`s. Regardless whether `query` is an element of `ls`, you still need to work with recursion to look to the remaining entries in `otherEntries`.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation and it clarified a lot for me! I was awestruck by how quickly you replied.
For the last few days I have been trying to solve the recursion issue and so far I have:

lookScan [] _ = []
lookScan ((id, ls): otherEntries) query
    | elem query ls = id:[]
    | otherwise = lookScan otherEntries query

It works just fine except for the case in which the queried value appears for several IDs, just like "value3" does in my original question. It finds only the first ID but does not proceed with any others.

What would you presume the problem is?

Comment: You need to *recurse*, both in case the item is an element, and if it is *not* an element.